# Why do we assume that we can change the past by sending signals backwards in time?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, time-travel, tachyon

This might be a stupid question, but hang in with me-
From what I've seen, the biggest argument against superluminal signaling is that you would be able to send a message backwards in time that could change something in the past and thereby create a paradox.  For example, with access to a bunch of tachyons, you could send a message to an assassin several years in the past, telling that assassin to murder you as an infant for an immensely large sum of money.  Assuming the assassin succeeds, this clearly creates a paradox, since your adult self no longer exists to be able to send the assassin the message.

However, I am greatly puzzled by the fact that we have assumed that this scenario is even possible.  It seems to me that it is impossible to change events in the past even if you could send information backwards in time, simply because the past has already happened.  In other words, there is nothing new about that message that you sent backwards in time - it was already received in the past, and its consequences will neither change the past nor result in a new future.

(What I'm ultimately trying to get at: perhaps we shouldn't immediately discard superluminal phenomena when developing theories.)

Comment: its not discarded immediately, e.g. tachyon is a well known concept in physics, there are also closed timelike curves in general relativity that allow travel to your past. Physics is not dismissing these ideas, its just that unless someone actually constructs time-machine or observes faster than light travel or closed timelike curves, physicists will remain skeptical (not dismissive) to the whole thing.

Comment: When it comes to grandfather paradox, you are correct that it is not inevitable, but it still shows an issue with time travel and cyclic causal relations. Strictly speaking, we do not know how something like that would work. This is most easily seen if you consider free will - your past and future choices need to be "in sync" for paradox not to arise. But why would they be? What forces you to make only consistent choices? It might be that it will work somehow, but without working time machine we can only speculate.